# Using Access yes/no in where clause of a SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, where-clause, sqldatasource

I'm trying to populate a dropdownlist control using a `SqlDataSource`. The data source has a `WHERE` clause to a yes/no column in access. However when I run the website the DropDownlist control does not populate, even after `control.bind` in `pageload`.

Question is:

In creating the `SqlDatasource`, which source should I use for a column that has yes/no types to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an Access database, why not use the `System.Data.Odbc` or maybe even `System.Data.OleDb` connections instead of `System.Data.Sql`.

**Check this possibility, too:** When using the `System.Data.Sql` driver, you may find there are connection specific properties for accessing Microsoft Access databases--so do some reading on this in the MSDN.

A `yes`/`no` column is simply a `Boolean` column in SQL Server parlance. In Access, you can set `yes`/`no` columns to the following values: (yes, true, 1)|(no, false, 0). I believe in T-SQL for SQL Server, Boolean columns must be either: (true, 1)|(false, 0).

HTH.